# Why will PayPal not recognise my Items Array?

Tags: javascript, paypal

I am currently building a website that has a store section in it and I am trying to integrate the PayPal Smart buttons. I want PayPal to give them the list of times at checkout and I know that I have to do this using the "items: []" array. But I want the items to change based on what the users have in their cart. My cart is integrated using VanillaCartJS and here is my cart.js file:

```js
'use strict';

let cart = (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart')) || []);
const cartDOM = document.querySelector('.cart');
const addToCartButtonsDOM = document.querySelectorAll('[data-action="ADD_TO_CART"]');

if (cart.length > 0) {
    cart.forEach(cartItem => {
        const product = cartItem;
        insertItemToDOM(product);
        countCartTotal();

        addToCartButtonsDOM.forEach(addToCartButtonDOM => {
            const productDOM = addToCartButtonDOM.parentNode;

            if (productDOM.querySelector('.product__name').innerText === product.name) {
                handleActionButtons(addToCartButtonDOM, product);
            }
        });

    });
}

addToCartButtonsDOM.forEach(addToCartButtonDOM => {
    addToCartButtonDOM.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const productDOM = addToCartButtonDOM.parentNode;
        const product = {
            image: productDOM.querySelector('.product__image').getAttribute('src'),
            name: productDOM.querySelector('.product__name').innerText,
            price: productDOM.querySelector('.product__price').innerText,
            quantity: 1,
        };

        const isInCart = (cart.filter(cartItem => (cartItem.name === product.name)).length > 0);

        if (!isInCart) {
            insertItemToDOM(product);
            cart.push(product);
            saveCart();
            handleActionButtons(addToCartButtonDOM, product);
        }
    });
});

function insertItemToDOM(product) {
    cartDOM.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
    <div class="cart__item">
      <img class="cart__item__image" src="${product.image}" alt="${product.name}">
      <h3 class="cart__item__name">${product.name}</h3>
      <h3 class="cart__item__price">${product.price}</h3>
      <button class="btn btn--primary btn--small${(product.quantity === 1 ? ' btn--danger' : '')}" data-action="DECREASE_ITEM">&minus;</button>
      <h3 class="cart__item__quantity">${product.quantity}</h3>
      <button class="btn btn--primary btn--small" data-action="INCREASE_ITEM">&plus;</button>
      <button class="btn btn--danger btn--small" data-action="REMOVE_ITEM">&times;</button>
    </div>
  `);

    addCartFooter();
}

function handleActionButtons(addToCartButtonDOM, product) {
    addToCartButtonDOM.innerText = 'In Cart';
    addToCartButtonDOM.disabled = true;

    const cartItemsDOM = cartDOM.querySelectorAll('.cart__item');
    cartItemsDOM.forEach(cartItemDOM => {
        if (cartItemDOM.querySelector('.cart__item__name').innerText === product.name) {
            cartItemDOM.querySelector('[data-action="INCREASE_ITEM"]').addEventListener('click', () => increaseItem(product, cartItemDOM));
            cartItemDOM.querySelector('[data-action="DECREASE_ITEM"]').addEventListener('click', () => decreaseItem(product, cartItemDOM, addToCartButtonDOM));
            cartItemDOM.querySelector('[data-action="REMOVE_ITEM"]').addEventListener('click', () => removeItem(product, cartItemDOM, addToCartButtonDOM));
        }
    });
}

function increaseItem(product, cartItemDOM) {
    cart.forEach(cartItem => {
        if (cartItem.name === product.name) {
            cartItemDOM.querySelector('.cart__item__quantity').innerText = ++cartItem.quantity;
            cartItemDOM.querySelector('[data-action="DECREASE_ITEM"]').classList.remove('btn--danger');
            saveCart();
        }
    });
}

function decreaseItem(product, cartItemDOM, addToCartButtonDOM) {
    cart.forEach(cartItem => {
        if (cartItem.name === product.name) {
            if (cartItem.quantity > 1) {
                cartItemDOM.querySelector('.cart__item__quantity').innerText = --cartItem.quantity;
                saveCart();
            } else {
                removeItem(product, cartItemDOM, addToCartButtonDOM);
            }

            if (cartItem.quantity === 1) {
                cartItemDOM.querySelector('[data-action="DECREASE_ITEM"]').classList.add('btn--danger');
            }
        }
    });
}

function removeItem(product, cartItemDOM, addToCartButtonDOM) {
    cartItemDOM.classList.add('cart__item--removed');
    setTimeout(() => cartItemDOM.remove(), 250);
    cart = cart.filter(cartItem => cartItem.name !== product.name);
    saveCart();
    addToCartButtonDOM.innerText = 'Add To Cart';
    addToCartButtonDOM.disabled = false;

    if (cart.length < 1) {
        document.querySelector('.cart-footer').remove();
    }
}

function addCartFooter() {
    if (document.querySelector('.cart-footer') === null) {
        cartDOM.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `
      <div class="cart-footer">
        <button data-action="CLEAR_CART">Clear Cart</button>
        <p data-action="CHECKOUT">Total:</p>
      </div>
    `);

        document.querySelector('[data-action="CLEAR_CART"]').addEventListener('click', () => clearCart());
    }
}

function clearCart() {
    cartDOM.querySelectorAll('.cart__item').forEach(cartItemDOM => {
        cartItemDOM.classList.add('cart__item--removed');
        setTimeout(() => cartItemDOM.remove(), 250);
    });

    cart = [];
    localStorage.removeItem('cart');
    document.querySelector('.cart-footer').remove();

    addToCartButtonsDOM.forEach(addToCartButtonDOM => {
        addToCartButtonDOM.innerText = 'Add To Cart';
        addToCartButtonDOM.disabled = false;
    });
}

function countCartTotal() {
    let cartTotal = 0;
    cart.forEach(cartItem => cartTotal += cartItem.quantity * cartItem.price);
    document.querySelector('[data-action="CHECKOUT"]').innerText = `Pay $${cartTotal}`;
    return cartTotal;
}

function saveCart() {
    localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
    countCartTotal();
}

function arrayOfItems (cartItem, product)
{
    let cartItemName = cartItem.name;
    'use strict';

    let cart = (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart')) || []);
    const cartDOM = document.querySelector('.cart');
    const addToCartButtonsDOM = document.querySelectorAll('[data-action="ADD_TO_CART"]');

    if (cart.length > 0) {
        cart.forEach(cartItem => {
            const product = cartItem;
            insertItemToDOM(product);
            countCartTotal();

            addToCartButtonsDOM.forEach(addToCartButtonDOM => {
                const productDOM = addToCartButtonDOM.parentNode;

                if (productDOM.querySelector('.product__name').innerText === product.name) {
                    handleActionButtons(addToCartButtonDOM, product);
                }
            });

        });
    }

    addToCartButtonsDOM.forEach(addToCartButtonDOM => {
        addToCartButtonDOM.addEventListener('click', () => {
            const productDOM = addToCartButtonDOM.parentNode;
            const product = {
                image: productDOM.querySelector('.product__image').getAttribute('src'),
                name: productDOM.querySelector('.product__name').innerText,
                price: productDOM.querySelector('.product__price').innerText,
                quantity: 1,
            };

            const isInCart = (cart.filter(cartItem => (cartItem.name === product.name)).length > 0);

            if (!isInCart) {
                insertItemToDOM(product);
                cart.push(product);
                saveCart();
                handleActionButtons(addToCartButtonDOM, product);
            }
        });
    });

    function insertItemToDOM(product) {
        cartDOM.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
    <div class="cart__item">
      <img class="cart__item__image" src="${product.image}" alt="${product.name}">
      <h3 class="cart__item__name">${product.name}</h3>
      <h3 class="cart__item__price">${product.price}</h3>
      <button class="btn btn--primary btn--small${(product.quantity === 1 ? ' btn--danger' : '')}" data-action="DECREASE_ITEM">&minus;</button>
      <h3 class="cart__item__quantity">${product.quantity}</h3>
      <button class="btn btn--primary btn--small" data-action="INCREASE_ITEM">&plus;</button>
      <button class="btn btn--danger btn--small" data-action="REMOVE_ITEM">&times;</button>
    </div>
  `);

        addCartFooter();
    }

    function handleActionButtons(addToCartButtonDOM, product) {
        addToCartButtonDOM.innerText = 'In Cart';
        addToCartButtonDOM.disabled = true;

        const cartItemsDOM = cartDOM.querySelectorAll('.cart__item');
        cartItemsDOM.forEach(cartItemDOM => {
            if (cartItemDOM.querySelector('.cart__item__name').innerText === product.name) {
                cartItemDOM.querySelector('[data-action="INCREASE_ITEM"]').addEventListener('click', () => increaseItem(product, cartItemDOM));
                cartItemDOM.querySelector('[data-action="DECREASE_ITEM"]').addEventListener('click', () => decreaseItem(product, cartItemDOM, addToCartButtonDOM));
                cartItemDOM.querySelector('[data-action="REMOVE_ITEM"]').addEventListener('click', () => removeItem(product, cartItemDOM, addToCartButtonDOM));
            }
        });
    }

    function increaseItem(product, cartItemDOM) {
        cart.forEach(cartItem => {
            if (cartItem.name === product.name) {
                cartItemDOM.querySelector('.cart__item__quantity').innerText = ++cartItem.quantity;
                cartItemDOM.querySelector('[data-action="DECREASE_ITEM"]').classList.remove('btn--danger');
                saveCart();
            }
        });
    }

    function decreaseItem(product, cartItemDOM, addToCartButtonDOM) {
        cart.forEach(cartItem => {
            if (cartItem.name === product.name) {
                if (cartItem.quantity > 1) {
                    cartItemDOM.querySelector('.cart__item__quantity').innerText = --cartItem.quantity;
                    saveCart();
                } else {
                    removeItem(product, cartItemDOM, addToCartButtonDOM);
                }

                if (cartItem.quantity === 1) {
                    cartItemDOM.querySelector('[data-action="DECREASE_ITEM"]').classList.add('btn--danger');
                }
            }
        });
    }

    function removeItem(product, cartItemDOM, addToCartButtonDOM) {
        cartItemDOM.classList.add('cart__item--removed');
        setTimeout(() => cartItemDOM.remove(), 250);
        cart = cart.filter(cartItem => cartItem.name !== product.name);
        saveCart();
        addToCartButtonDOM.innerText = 'Add To Cart';
        addToCartButtonDOM.disabled = false;

        if (cart.length < 1) {
            document.querySelector('.cart-footer').remove();
        }
    }

    function addCartFooter() {
        if (document.querySelector('.cart-footer') === null) {
            cartDOM.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `
      <div class="cart-footer">
        <button data-action="CLEAR_CART">Clear Cart</button>
        <p data-action="CHECKOUT">Total:</p>
      </div>
    `);

            document.querySelector('[data-action="CLEAR_CART"]').addEventListener('click', () => clearCart());
        }
    }

    function clearCart() {
        cartDOM.querySelectorAll('.cart__item').forEach(cartItemDOM => {
            cartItemDOM.classList.add('cart__item--removed');
            setTimeout(() => cartItemDOM.remove(), 250);
        });

        cart = [];
        localStorage.removeItem('cart');
        document.querySelector('.cart-footer').remove();

        addToCartButtonsDOM.forEach(addToCartButtonDOM => {
            addToCartButtonDOM.innerText = 'Add To Cart';
            addToCartButtonDOM.disabled = false;
        });
    }

    function countCartTotal() {
        let cartTotal = 0;
        cart.forEach(cartItem => cartTotal += cartItem.quantity * cartItem.price);
        document.querySelector('[data-action="CHECKOUT"]').innerText = `Pay $${cartTotal}`;
        return cartTotal;
    }

    function saveCart() {
        localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
        countCartTotal();
    }

}

function PayPalItems() {

    return cart.map((cartItem, index) => {
        ++index;
        let currency = cartItem.price;
        let quantity = cartItem.quantity;
        let itemName = cartItem.name;

        let items = [{"unit_amount": {"currency_code": "USD","value": currency},"quantity": quantity,"name": itemName,}];

        return items;
    });

}
```

It gets the cart items using things like "cartItem.name", "cartItem.price" and "cartItem.quantity". And The last function "PayPalItems()" is what I am trying to use to call the items array. It is as follows:

```js
function PayPalItems() {

    return cart.map((cartItem, index) => {
        ++index;
        let currency = cartItem.price;
        let quantity = cartItem.quantity;
        let itemName = cartItem.name;

        let items = [{"unit_amount": {"currency_code": "USD","value": currency},"quantity": quantity,"name": itemName,}];

        return items;
    });

}
```

In the script where I render the PayPal Buttons looks like this:

```js
<!-- JavaScript to call cart.js file and render PayPal Buttons -->
<script src="cart.js"></script>

<script>
    paypal.Buttons({
        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
            // This function sets up the details of the transaction, including the amount and line item details.
            return actions.order.create({
                "purchase_units": [{
                    "amount": {
                        "value": countCartTotal(),
                        "currency_code": "USD",
                        "breakdown": {
                            "item_total": {
                                "currency_code": "USD",
                                "value": countCartTotal()
                            },
                        },
                    },
                    "items": PayPalItems()
                }
                ]
            });
        },
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            // This function captures the funds from the transaction.
            return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                // This function shows a transaction success message to your buyer.
                window.location.href = "orderConfirmed.php";
                clearCart()
            });
        }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
    //This function displays Smart Payment Buttons on your web page.
</script>
```

In the value section, I use a function called "countCartTotal()" This adds up all the items in the cart to give a total that PayPal can then charge the user at checkout.  When I run the code, the user is charged the correct amount but the items are not displayed and when I look at the JavaScript Console I get the following error:

```
Error: /v2/checkout/orders returned status: 400 (Corr ID: 62dab91ed532d)
```

How can I fix this?

### Updates

The code for my PayPalItems() is:

```js
function PayPalItems() {

     return cart.forEach((cartItem, index) => {
        ++index;
        let currency = cartItem.price;
        let quantity = cartItem.quantity;
        let itemName = cartItem.name;

        const items = [{"unit_amount": {"currency_code": "USD","value": currency},"quantity": quantity,"name": itemName,}];
        console.log(items);
    });
}
```

And when I run this code on my localhost the PayPal buttons charge the correct amount but the items are not given. In my console log, this is what the JavaScript Console gives me:

[image]

This is with test data in the cart. The system is recognising what is there, it just won't output them in the PayPal sandbox window. I think it might be an issue with the [] but I'm not sure.

Comment: Print out what PayPalItems() returns / resolves to at runtime. `console.log(items)` in that function, or similar. And also what countCartTotal() is resolving to at the same time.

Comment: Thanks, @PrestonPHX I have done that and in the console log it gives me back what I need but it won't include it in PayPal, I will open a new question and link it in a comment below

Comment: Sigh, you should create fewer questions for the same issue, that information needed to go here as an edit

Comment: Okay I will edit this one

Comment: @PrestonPHX I have made the edits

Comment: Thinks issue with ssl, run local server in SSL mode. HTTPS mode. Use self sign certificate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You loop is wrong, *and* your debugging of the loop is wrong

`let items` need to be outside the loop and pre-initialize an empty array

inside the loop you need to add to items, not overwrite it

console.log(items); needs to be outside the loop, not inside it.

and then, you need to make sure you only actually return `items`, not cart.forEach .